# Unity: (js) Loading PNGs in assets folder to UI Image

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

In my Unity project, under a canvas, I created a blank UI Image.
On the other hand, in the assets folder, I have multiple PNGs.
I want the UI Image to be set as a random PNG from the folder via script.
How do I do that? Should I attach the script to the UI image or to the UI canvas? Can someone please show me an example script (js, not c#)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crate a folder named `Resources` and a subfolder named `Sprites`. Put your sprites in this folder (images must have the `Sprite` texture type in the image import settings, as pointed out by @SurajS).

Create an image element and attach the following UnityScript to it :

```
function Start () {
    var image : UnityEngine.UI.Image = GetComponent.<UnityEngine.UI.Image>();
    var sprites : Object[] = Resources.LoadAll("Sprites", Sprite);
    image.sprite = sprites[Random.Range(0, sprites.Length)] as Sprite;
}
```

---

Better solution (more efficient)

Attach the following script to the gameobject you want (your image, your canvas or even an empty)

```
#pragma strict

public var image : UnityEngine.UI.Image;

public var sprites : Sprite[];

function Start () {
    image.sprite = sprites[Random.Range(0, sprites.Length)] ;
}
```

Then, in the inspector, drag & drop the gameobject holding your image component in the `image` field, and put all the sprites you want in the `sprites` field.

---

To get the name of the sprites, you can do as follow :

```
var names : String[] = new String[sprites.Length] ;
for (var i = 0 ; i < names.Length ; ++i ) {
    names[i] = sprites[i].name;
}
```

Comment: Also, make sure that the PNG's import settings is set to Sprite or UI 2D.

Comment: thanks, it worked! A follow-up question: Meanwhile, I want to create an array of Strings that contain the names of the PNGs, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Check my updated answer. Don't forget to accept if it helped you.